# Coding automatic traffic light in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to code a traffic light program in Visual C# using a WinForms application. Basically what I want are three panels, each of one color : Red, Yellow, and Green. When one panel is 'on' the other panels will be gray. I want the panel which is 'on' to change every 15seconds.

For example, 
1) by default, "Red" is 'on' and "Yellow" and "Green" are gray.
2) 15 seconds later, "Yellow" is 'on' and "Red" and "Green" are gray
3) 15 seconds later, "Green" is 'on' and "Red" and "Yellow" are gray
4) 15 seconds later, "Red" is 'on' and "Yellow" and "Green" are gray

I managed to code a version where I can make it change colors via button presses, however, I don't know how to implement the 15 second timer.

Here is my current source code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Traffic_Light_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel_Red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            panel_Yellow.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            panel_Green.BackColor = Color.Gray;

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((panel_Yellow.BackColor == Color.Gray) == (panel_Green.BackColor == Color.Gray))
            {
                panel_Red.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                panel_Yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }

            else if (panel_Yellow.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
            {
                panel_Yellow.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                panel_Green.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }

            else
            {
                panel_Green.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                panel_Red.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first button sets the stage to 'Red' 'Gray' 'Gray' and upon clicks of the second button it changes to 'Gray' 'Yellow' 'Gray' > 'Gray' 'Gray' 'Green' > 'Red' 'Gray' 'Gray' and so on.

I want the change to happen automatically at 15second intervals.

Comment: You have to add timer component to your form. Set proper interval and make checks in Timer_Tick event.

Comment: Timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Make a timer the has a 15000 interval make sure it is set to enabeled then have an int that increases by 1 in the timer code. if the int % 3 = 0 red is on else if int%2 = 0 green is on else yellow is on

Answer (score 2):

From Toolbax -> Components drag Timer (last item listed) on your form. Go to properties window and set `Interval` property to 15000 (to raise tick event every 15 seconds) now select Events on properties window and double click on Tick event to produce proper event Handler. Be noticed that timer is Enable = false by default which means you have to turn it on from your code. Add this code to your application (Do not forget to mark answer):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Panel> _panels;
    private int _currentPanelIndex; 
    private List<Color> _colors;      

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _panels = new List<Panel> { panel_Red, panel_Yellow, panel_Green };
        _colors = new List<Color> {Color.Red,Color.Yellow,Color.Green};
        _currentPanelIndex = 0;

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void UpdatePanels()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        {
            if (index.Equals(_currentPanelIndex))
            {
                //current panel to be on
                _panels[index].BackColor = _colors[index];
            }
            else
            {
                //others are gray
                _panels[index].BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set current colors
        UpdatePanels();
        //move to next panel
        _currentPanelIndex++;
        //reset to start from first panel
        if (_currentPanelIndex.Equals(3))
        {
            _currentPanelIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```